# Fit_{p}(G)$ equals the intersection of the centralizers of the principal factor of G whose order is divisible by p.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

A finite group $G$ is said to be $p$-nilpotent (where $p$ is a prime) if it has a
normal Hall $p'$-subgroup, that is, if $O_{p'p}(G) = G$. Obviously every finite
nilpotent group is $p$-nilpotent; conversely a finite group which is $p$-nilpotent
for all $p$ is nilpotent. The product of all the normal $p$-nilpotent subgroups of a finite group is clearly $O_{p'p}(G)$: this is the maximum normal $p$-nilpotent subgroup of $G$ and
we shall also write it $Fit_{p}(G)$, the $p$-Fitting subgroup.

I want prove if G is a finite group, then $Fit_{p}(G)$ equals the intersection of the centralizers of the principal factor of G whose order is divisible by p.

For this i let $H$ be a normal $p$-nilpotent subgroup of $G$. How by induction on $|G|$ can show $H$ is centralizes every principal factor whose order is divisible by $p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N/M$ be a chief factor (I think that means the same as principal factor) of $G$ of order divisible by $p$. Then $HM/M$ is a normal $p$-nilpotent subgroup of $G/M$, and $N/M$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G/M$ so, by the previous post, $[HM/M,N/M] = 1 \Rightarrow [HM,N] \le M \Rightarrow [H,M] \le N$.

But you still need to prove the other direction that the intersection of the centralizers of the chief factors with order divisible by $p$ is $p$-nilpotent.

Comment: what do you show ? How the other direction ? can you explain ?